# Routing in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. I'm trying to setup my routes in the RouteConfig.cs file. Essentially, I have two URLs I'm currently interested in. Those URLs are:

```
/App
/App/Auth
```

My file structure looks like the following:

```
/Views
  App
    Index.cshtml
    Auth
      Index.cshtml
  Docs
    Index.cshtml
  Index.cshtml
```

In my RouteConfig.cs file, I have the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
  "Index",
  "Index",
  new { controller = "Views", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Dashboard", // Route name
  "{controller}/auth/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Oddly, when I visit /App/Auth it takes me to /App. For the life of me, I can't figure out why. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your problem: when you visit /App/Auth which controller's which action is called and what should be the expected result?

Comment: If you need more insight into how your routes are being interpreted, try the route debugger available via nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is doing exactly what you asked.  Your first route goes to controller "App" and action "Index".  Move the folder Auth to same level as App and then change your route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Dashboard", // Route name
  "app/auth/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

**An even better solution**, forget the Auth controller and just create a view auth.cshtml in the App folder and an action "Auth" in the App controller, and then you can delete the route altogether and /app/auth will get handled by the default route.

Answer (score 0):

Change the route to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Dashboard", // Route name
  "App/auth/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```